# Does a Corda node verify a transaction before storing it?

Tags: corda

If `A` creates some state with `participants` of `A` and `B`, and signs it, but *doesn't* require `B`'s signature, I see that the state still gets replicated to `B`'s ledger.

Does the state's contract's `verify` function still get run on `B`'s side? Or do I have to code that explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

`A` will send the transaction by invoking `SendTransactionFlow`. `B` will respond by invoking `ReceiveTransactionFlow`.

As part of `ReceiveTransactionFlow`, `B` will verify the transaction, and optionally the signatures (based on the `checkSufficientSignatures` parameter).